# Oracle : Selecting the values of column based on the values in other column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I wanted to a table like below :

```
Class_ID    Student_ID     Sub_ID
3171         10577752         1
3171         10577753         1
3171         10577753         2
3171         10577754         1
3171         10577755         1
3171         10577755         2
3172         10577756         1
3172         10577756         2
3172         10577756         3
3172         10577757         1
3172         10577757         2
3172         10577758         1
```

So I wanted to select the student_id that are in all the sub_id. For. eg : in class_id 3171 the total sub_id is 2(1 and 2) and the student_id 10577753 is there in sub_id 1 and 2 both but the id
10577752 is there in only the sub_id 1. so i wanted to select 10577753 and 10577755 for class_id 3171. Class_ID 2172 has the total sub_id 3(1,2,3) and the student_id 10577756 is there in all three. so i wanted to select only these student_id 10577753,10577755,10577756 from the above table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option (sample data till line #26): `temp` CTE calculates number of distinct `STU_ID`s, partitioned by student (`cnt_stu`) or class (`cnt_tot`). *Winners* are students whose counts match.

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (class_id, student_id, sub_id)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 3171, 10577752, 1 FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 3171, 10577753, 1 FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 3171, 10577753, 2 FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 3171, 10577754, 1 FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 3171, 10577755, 1 FROM DUAL
 13         UNION ALL
 14         SELECT 3171, 10577755, 2 FROM DUAL
 15         UNION ALL
 16         SELECT 3172, 10577756, 1 FROM DUAL
 17         UNION ALL
 18         SELECT 3172, 10577756, 2 FROM DUAL
 19         UNION ALL
 20         SELECT 3172, 10577756, 3 FROM DUAL
 21         UNION ALL
 22         SELECT 3172, 10577757, 1 FROM DUAL
 23         UNION ALL
 24         SELECT 3172, 10577757, 2 FROM DUAL
 25         UNION ALL
 26         SELECT 3172, 10577758, 1 FROM DUAL),
```

---

```
 27     temp
 28     AS
 29        (SELECT class_id,
 30                student_id,
 31                sub_id,
 32                COUNT (DISTINCT sub_id)
 33                   OVER (PARTITION BY class_id, student_id) cnt_stu,
 34                COUNT (DISTINCT sub_id) OVER (PARTITION BY class_id) cnt_tot
 35           FROM test)
 36    SELECT DISTINCT student_id
 37      FROM temp
 38     WHERE cnt_stu = cnt_tot
 39  ORDER BY student_id;

STUDENT_ID
----------
  10577753
  10577755
  10577756

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Count distinct. Use a `HAVING` clause to compare the students' counts with their classes' counts.

```
select class_id, student_id
from mytable t1
group by class_id, student_id
having count(distinct sub_id) =
(
  select count(distinct sub_id)
  from mytable t2
  where t2.class_id = t1.class_id
)
order by class_id, student_id;
```

another way to write this:

```
select class_id, student_id
from mytable
group by class_id, student_id
having (class_id, count(distinct sub_id)) in
(
  select class_id, count(distinct sub_id)
  from mytable
  group by class_id
)
order by class_id, student_id;
```

The difference is that the first query uses a correlated subquery and the second a non-correlated one. But they do the same thing after all.